# checking syntax of php-code w/o php-cli, possible?

Tags: php, syntax, error-handling

Is it possible to check syntax of php-code (without running),
similar to the

```
php-cli -l
```

when running php the "ordinary" way (as a module)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are also some PECL extensions which parse PHP code for various reasons. First there is [BCompiler](http://pecl.php.net/package/bcompiler), which can compile a PHP into byte code. Since this step requires parsing the PHP code, I would expect errors if it isn't lint. [Parsekit](http://pecl.php.net/package/parsekit) allwos you to compile PHP code to OP codes, which is basically what you desire. However, the extension did not have a release since late 2009, so it might be outdated. [Parse_Tree](http://pecl.php.net/package/Parse_Tree) is sadly unmaintained since 2007, but its purpose is to parse a PHP file into an AST. Maybe you can get to something with this one, after some polishing.

[PHP_Parser](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Parser) is a PEAR package, which does not rely on special PHP extensions and attempts to parse PHP code from within PHP. Its marked alpha and unmaintained, but it might give you a basis to experiment with.

Comment: Then you'll probably end up writing it on your own. :)

Comment: request of reopening php_check_syntax filed at php.net.

Comment: contact with dev at php.net. check_syntax was removed due to execution of require:ed scripts. Closing this for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run a tool like [PHP Depend](http://pdepend.org/) on the sources, which attempts to parse the given PHP files into an abstract syntax tree. While this might not catch all PHP parser errors, it will already catch quite a lot of them.

You get nice software metrics as an additional goodie, if the code is valid. :)

Comment: Thanks for the info, however, for the purpose, I'd prefer a more dead simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to check syntax of php-code (without running), similar to the php-cli -l
>   when running php the "ordinary" way (as a module)?

I think the question everyone missed is that there is no difference in PHP syntax whether you run it as a module, or simply execute the binary from a shell: the PHP syntax is the same on both occasions. So, you might as well just use php -l filename.php, as that has the exact same result as using the tools listed above.

Comment: well aware of that, however, not having to rely on installed php-cli would be a benefit.

Answer (score -1):

For getting the same result as php-cli -l, use the function: php_check_syntax

Comment: (PHP 5 <= 5.0.4) "For technical reasons, this function is deprecated and removed from PHP." It also executes the file, but OP states "without running".

Comment: -1.  Look at the docs.  that function was removed in 5.0.5: http://us.php.net/php_check_syntax

Comment: php_check_syntax executes the code. But the comments on http://php.net/php_check_syntax are worth a read.

Comment: You are right, guys, I didn't noticed that it was deprecated. I guess then a good option is to make system call to 'php-cli -l', if you are able to.

Comment: It's not deprecated.  It doesn't exist.  it was removed!  Trying to call it will cause a missing function error...

Comment: now would a suggestion such as eval($code,$syntaxCheckOnly) be an awful suggestion to the php-devs?